# Do Google Drive and Ubuntu One have the same concept?

Tags: cloud, google-docs, google-drive

Do Google Drive and Ubuntu One have the same concept?

I just have an Ubuntu cloud account and Google Docs.

Comment: cloud is a concept - google drive is an implementation of one of the aspects of cloud computing

Comment: @Shakehar Thnkz.But still i hv dbt.In both we can store our data files and access from anywhere.Is this is the function both are doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, yes, they're the same.

To all intents and purposes, the 'cloud' is the internet.  Google Drive, Ubuntu cloud services, MS Skydrive and the multitude of other 'cloud service providers' essentially give you the ability to store information in a way that it can be retrieved by you, anywhere there is connectivity to the 'cloud'.  This type of cloud computing is known as [Storage as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_as_a_service) (STaaS)

The implementation details differ: some providers link a physical drive on your machine to the cloud, so that you are accessing information stored on your own hard drive, some give you storage space on their hardware,  but the end result is the same.  Your data is held in a location accessible by the internet, so that you can access it, whenever you are connected to the internet (cloud).

Comment: thnks.If accessing  from harddrive of our system does it means cloud account can access systems drive at anytime?is the drive itself is shared in internet? or a copy of drive?But i guess if share drive means we need to upload data in that drive to cloud?i did it.means data is uploaded to cloud(ubuntu one)

Comment: Yes you can access the drive anytime you can connect to the internet.  It depends on the provider but I think most of them copy data to their hardware.  Dropbox uses a drive on your machine, but I don't know if they link that to their hardware, or copy all the content.

Comment: Even if my system is off, still is it possible for cloud to connect to drive if i access cloud account from some other system ??? .srry in advance if am asking a foolish qus.

Comment: Let me clear up a little confusion: **Cloud services give you some space on _their_ machines, which are (almost) always running.** You can choose to sync some of your own drive to the cloud, if you like.  No matter where you are, you can access your cloud account and the data stored on it. @mcalex Dropbox is similar to the others, it auto-syncs between a cloud drive and your "dropbox folder".

Comment: @MarcusChan thnkz for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 4):

To answer simply, **yes, they are the same concept**. Ubuntu One and Google Drive are competitors that seek to provide the same service of keeping your data for you so you can access it anywhere. There are lots of practical differences between them, and reasons why one would be more convenient than the other, but just like Facebook and Google+, they're the same kind of thing. Mind you, the same reasons apply to having multiple cloud storage accounts as having multiple social networking accounts: different ones are better for different things.

Edit: I automatically assumed you meant Ubuntu One when you said an "Ubuntu Cloud account", is that what you meant? Canonical also has the "Ubuntu cloud" name assigned to something else entirely.

Comment: thnkz .ya i was talking abt Ubuntu one. But i guess Ubuntu one is accessible only in Linux environment.Also both are only used for storing data in a common location which can be accessed from anywhere?

Comment: Nope, **Ubuntu One has clients for Windows, Mac and Linux**. Google Drive does as well, and a (really well-made) web client. They both have other features, too; for example Ubuntu One does music streaming.

Comment: ok.that means to access ubuntu one in windows i need to install something seperatly??

Comment: Yep, https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows/.